# Read Data from Kafka Broker at Specific Time Intervals (Python)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I have a system where a machine is reading data and continuously appends a .txt file. This dataset is read into a Kafka broker via Kafka Connect and would then be pre-processed with some Python code. The machine operates roughly every 5 mins, so we would expect data to come in, and then be idle for 5 mins. until the next batch. The Kafka setup is fine, so please assume everything upstream of this code is working properly.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer
import json

KAFKA_BROKER_URL = 'localhost:9092'
live_data = []

def parse_poll_message(msg):
    row = json.loads(msg)
    split_msg = list(row['payload'].split('\t'))
    return split_msg

consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': KAFKA_BROKER_URL,
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
    'enable.auto.commit': True
})


consumer.subscribe(['my_topic'])

while 1:
    msg = consumer.poll()
    if msg is None:
        break
    elif msg.error():
        print("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue
    else:
        live_data.append(parse_poll_message(msg.value().decode('utf-8')))

consumer.close()
```

The code above just demonstrates what I would do at one point in time. What I would like to do is every 5 minutes, collect all the messages at that time, convert them into a dataframe, perform some calculations, and then wait for the next set of messages. How do I keep this loop active while retaining messages in the correct time interval?

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a (constantly running) pyspark, Flink, or Beam job since they actually supports such tumbling windowing functions with watermarks to create dataframes... Otherwise, it's not clear what's shutting down your consumers after every time interval since you have an infinite loop while messages are present (e.g. assume you have a really large lag that takes more than 5 minutes to read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried passing a time interval to the poll function?

```
while 1:
    msg = consumer.poll(300000) # listen for 5 minutes of data
    if msg is None:
        break
    elif msg.error():
        print("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue
    else:
        live_data.append(parse_poll_message(msg.value().decode('utf-8')))
```

This will leave the consumer wait for the messages in the 5 minutes timeframe and then do your processing

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This question had been posted some time back, so I had forgotten that it was posted. Your solution is exactly how I went about solving the issue.

Comment: will it return list of messages which is pushed with in 5minutes interval?